# Moving Azure credentials to Docker

Tags: azure, docker, azure-ad-msal, adal

I have a Docker volume from `${USERPROFILE}/.azure` to `/root/.azure:rw`. In my `Dockerfile`, I'm installing `az-cli` and then using `DefaultAzureCredentials` class in .NET (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet) to load the credentials.

It worked fine until a month ago, I had to `az login` on my machine and then it worked fine in Docker. However, about a month ago, when `az-cli` switched from ADAL to MSAL, it throws an exception saying I'm not logged in.

My guess is that `az-cli` stores the tokens somewhere else now, other than the `.azure` directory, or something else, I'm not sure. Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Have you ever considered using a service identity?

Answer (score 1):

Earlier, Azure CLI save ADAL tokens and service principal entries to **~/.azure/accessToken.json**

Later when Azure CLI use MSAL, it no longer generate **accessTokens.json** file.

**Any existing workflow depending on accessTokens.json no longer works**

So instead of **DefaultAzureCredentials** class, you can use **AzureCliCredential** class

**AzureCliCredential** class uses subprocess to call **az account get-access-toke**n to get an access token for the current logged-in account

**Reference**: [MSAL-based Azure CLI | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/msal-based-azure-cli)

Comment: One of the fallbacks in `DefaultAzureCredentials` ***is*** `AzureCliCredential`. The reason I use `DefaultAzureCredentials` is to use the CLI on my local environment, but on my actual production I want to use other authentication methods. I don't see how that solves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

For now you can use a pre-2.30 az-cli version both on your host system and inside your container. Instructions are here to install a specific version: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli